# Enumerators vs. returning

Tags: ruby, iterator

I've been reading over the [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001515) module in Ruby, and it contains a few methods that follow the pattern of

```
enum.foo(n) {|obj| block } → nil
enum.foo(n) → an_enumerator
```

Which is to say, they seem to return an iterator when chained and nothing otherwise. What's the reasoning behind taking this approach instead of just returning a sequence? (I'm asking about general reasoning for this approach, not necessarily just its use in Ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it was introduced to better support chaining of operations. It can be too expensive to generate unnecessary intermediate objects.

See for example https://github.com/rdp/ruby_tutorials_core/wiki/enumerator

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure of the differences between the two approaches in Ruby but in C# we have the yield keyword (that can only be used when returning IEnumerable or IEnumerable (the generic Enumerable). What the yield keyword does is create a closure over the current environment creating an enumerator that uses that closure. It's easier to demonstrate in code than talk about it. Here is a Fibonnaci generator using yield:

```
public IEnumerable<long> Fibonnaci()
{
  long current, previous;
  if(current==0)
    yield return current++;
  (for byte i=2;i<128;i++) //Fibonacci numbers grow big quickly.
  {
    long tmp=current+previous;
    previous=current;
    current=tmp;
    yield return tmp;
  }
}
```

Note that I don't have to use recursion, I just evaluate my current value and return. Now if I want to get the xth Fibonnaci number I just create a function like so:

```
public long GetFibonacciNumber(byte count)
{
   byte currentCount;
   foreach(long value in Fibonacci())
   {
     if(++currentCount<count)
       break;
     return value;
   }
}
```

Powerful stuff.